# Limit the launch of an application functionality

Tags: encryption, java

I have an application (written in Java) and I want to limit the launch of one of its functionality (e.g. start a certain functionality maximum 1000 times). The application is inside the company Intranet and cannot use public Internet. One trivial solution could be to save the number of launch time in an encrypted file but this file can be copied and overwritten by the system administrator of the company (where the application runs). One other solution could be to using some lightweight database but I don't want to utilize a database system just to store one decreasing number.
Do you have any idea how to store this number securely?

Comment: why not a global variable that decrements?

Comment: Limit until a timestamp. Setting the system clock back is so eww yucky, chances are customer staff would refuse to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no secure way. Once the application is in full control of the user it can be analyzed and every idea you have can be defeated. That's why you have software where the license restrictions are removed, have hacks to work around (offline) DRM etc.

The usual way is to make hacking around your restriction too hard. This can be done by restring ways to debug the application, obfuscating the checks as much as possible and interweaving them with the rest of the application so that attempts to hack around your restriction will cause the application to malfunction.